# python telnet socket connection recv encoding type

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

**python telnet socket connection recv encoding type**

connect telnet using socket but i can not decode result recv

this is my encoding string

> '\xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f'

how i can decode it

i have try all of this and it is not working

```
> ascii big5 big5hkscs cp037 cp273 cp424 cp437 cp500 cp720 cp737 cp775
> cp850 cp852 cp855 cp856 cp857 cp858 cp860 cp861 cp862 cp863 cp864
> cp865 cp866 cp869 cp874 cp875 cp932 cp949 cp950 cp1006 cp1026 cp1125
> cp1140 cp1250 cp1251 cp1252 cp1253 cp1254 cp1255 cp1256 cp1257 cp1258
> cp65001 euc_jp euc_jis_2004 euc_jisx0213 euc_kr gb2312 gbk gb18030 hz
> iso2022_jp iso2022_jp_1 iso2022_jp_2 iso2022_jp_2004 iso2022_jp_3
> iso2022_jp_ext iso2022_kr latin_1 iso8859_2 iso8859_3 iso8859_4
> iso8859_5 iso8859_6 iso8859_7 iso8859_8 iso8859_9 iso8859_10
> iso8859_11 iso8859_13 iso8859_14 iso8859_15 iso8859_16 johab koi8_r
> koi8_t koi8_u kz1048 mac_cyrillic mac_greek mac_iceland mac_latin2
> mac_roman mac_turkish ptcp154 shift_jis shift_jis_2004 shift_jisx0213
> utf_32 utf_32_be utf_32_le utf_16 utf_16_be utf_16_le utf_7 utf_8
> utf_8_sig
```

and this is my code

```
import socket
import gzip
s = socket.socket()
#Connecting using telnet
s.connect((HOST,23))
a = s.recv(1000)
```

Comment: a = s.recv(1000), "utf-8"

Comment: What does "decode" mean? Do you know what you actually want to do?

Comment: i think that string is some english words  how to convert encodeing text to real text

Comment: no it is not utf-8 it is not working

Comment: telnet is a protocol, not a bunch of strings. You might find the [telnet library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) to be the right software tool for this.

Comment: what is this \xff\xfb\x01\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x1f encoding type